# ASP.NET C# MVC Best way to store lots of information/value without using database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for an approach to solve my problem (total newbie here), so basically I am creating a page that user can input their computer specifications and submit to generate a PDF report (basically containing their computer specs with our logo). The thing is that I don't want to store the value/data input by user inside a database. Is there other approach? I was thinking to generate the PDF file directly and store inside our hard drive and next time they can access it directly there but it seems to be expensive in the long term.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Guess we need a little bit more information here. Must the information the user entered by stored on the server at all (PDF or whatever) or is it just a transformation of the user-input sent back to the user as downloadable PDF? If the later is the case: what did you try already and where is the problem?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to store the information in the database? Does the application allows users to check the pdf history and download it? If not, then you can just let users enter the required information everytime they wanted to get the pdf file. You can for example, store the last information in the browser session storage.

Comment: What you can do is store the data in `server memory`,for that you can create a `store class` to store the user input information inside of it and from the `caller class` in its constructor create an object for the `store class`(make sure that you have declared the class in the scope of the caller class) then on your submit(or any event pass data to the class)  use that `store class` to to generate your pdf by passing the `store class object` to the pdf generator function.

Comment: " it seems to be expensive in the long term."...depends how many users and files you think you might end up with. It would almost certainly take up more disk space than a database entry though, yes. And it's not very flexible - doesn't allow for amendments etc. Plus, you still need some way to index your documents, so that if a particular user wants to retrieve their document later then you have a lookup to find it. So it's likely you'll still end up with a database anyway, because most other methods (e.g. flat file) don't work very well in multi-user scenarios. Just use a database!

Comment: @Marc Thanks for the reply. The idea is that we want the user to enter the information and then can download the PDF, in the future, the person can come back and download that same PDF/Info that he entered. The reason why we don't want to use database is that, the Form has around 300 fields to be filled. Generating PDF is not a problem, just thinking if there's any other approach to store the data

Comment: @hendryanw Thanks for the reply. Yup, correct the user can check the pdf history and download it. The reason why we don't want to use the database is that there are 300 fields that need to be filled and we are not interested with the information entered by the user.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the reply. The reason why we don't want to use the DB is that there are around 300 fields that need to be filled and we are not interested with the data at all (so no sorting/amendmends, etc). We want the user to be able to input the data and download it in the future, my plan is either use JSON or XML to store the data

Comment: and when you do it like that, how will you identify which document (or XML snippet) matches which user when they come to retrieve it? P.S. You could still store XML or JSON _within_ a single field in a database, if you're not so interested in the specifics of that, and index it against a username or whatever, so you can easily (and efficiently, without searching the disk or parsing a massive XML document) retrieve it later.

Comment: @ADyson My plan is to create a JSON file with the user_id since only one user can have one report file. What do you think?

Comment: disk access will likely be slower than SQL access but yeah it could work, as long as the number of files doesn't get too large (which can slow down disk access even more). How many user records do you anticipate having?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in XML files using XML serialization.

Check following `pseudo` code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlMvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Serializable]
    public class TestData
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SaveItems(string id, string name)
        {
            TestData obj = new TestData();
            obj.id = id;
            obj.Name = name;
            string file = Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + "\\" + id + ".xml";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
                System.IO.File.Delete(file);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.CreateNew);
            //store into xml file
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestData));
            x.Serialize(fs, obj);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetItems(string id)
        {
            string file = Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + "\\" + id + ".xml";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
            {
                XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(file);

                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestData));
                var nodes = xml.Descendants("TestData")
                .Select(rr => xmlSerializer.Deserialize(rr.CreateReader()) as TestData);
                var deSerializedData = nodes.First();
                //YOUR CODE HERE
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```